# Docker create command hangs on "Waiting for host to start"

Tags: docker

### Docker hangs when I try to create a docker node

I am trying to set up a docker node as per step 4 of [the instructions on docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#example). Unfortunately, Whenever I run the "create" command in the command prompt, the process hangs on

> (testNode1) Waiting for host to start...

### The instruction set is roughly as follows:

1. Enable HyperV (done)
2. Set up external network switch (done)
3. Reboot (done)
4. Create nodes (hangs)

The document explicitly states that step 3 is included to prevent exactly this error from happening. However, I have completed that step, and I still encounter this error.

### Solutions I have tried

Other sources have suggested that I'm either targeting the wrong network switch, or that the one I've created is not set to "external". I have verified that the switch is set to "external" and that the correct network switch is being targeted, so that does not seem to be the problem.

I have also made sure to restart my machine a few times already, so I doubt another reboot on its own will help.

I also left it running for a day to see if it would eventually resolve itself, but it did not.

### Additional details

The command I'm using is:

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "VirtualSwitchName" testNode1
```

I am using Docker version 18.09

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise.

The node is hosted on Hyper-V

Comment: how long have you waited ? creating a completely new docker machine takes time

Comment: I left it on "waiting" for nearly three days, and I've waited nearly three hours on my most recent attempt.

Comment: lol yup thats enough :D

Comment: do you have windows 10 Pro ?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise. I do not have the option to alter this.

Comment: no thats ok enterprise should work as well but for the plain windows 10 there is another docker setup

Comment: did you forget "-d hyperv" ? (the hyperv after -d)

Comment: I did not forget it when executing the command, though I *did* forget it when initially typing this question.

Comment: I did not when executing it, but I *did* forget when writing this question.

Comment: how about without the quotes on the switch

Comment: Done. I can see that the node has been created and is running, but it seems to still hang in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure the Docker version is compatible with the Windows version

There are multiple versions of Docker Enterprise. Each successive version has improved functionality, but each version also requires a more up-to-date version of Windows 10.

For example, if you are trying to run Docker 18.09, then you need Windows 10 version 1809 or higher. Docker 18.09 is simply not compatible with earlier versions of Windows 10.

### How to check for a compatible Docker version

There is a useful chart [here](https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix) detailing which versions of Docker are compatible with which operating systems. This will tell you what the highest version of Docker is that you can run based on your current OS.

To check your OS version, open your command prompt and type "winver". This will bring up a popup telling you what version of windows you are running (for example, Windows 10, Version 1709). Use this and the above chart to determine if your current version of Docker is compatible with your current OS.